# Image stored in Amazon S3 can not display on chrome

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to store all static files (EX: picture, CSS, ...) on the Amazon S3 service so it can be quick loading on my website. Then I get this issue :

Image store on S3 only displays with Firefox Web browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3XOH.png

With Chrome or Edge, it turns into transparent or not display, sometimes it displayed but it took at least 3 days: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OreZa.png

Image link: https://dt18ria0o1of5.cloudfront.net/Wowpay-logo/Logos/unknowLogo.svg

Network image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OgH8.png

I have tried to clean cache, local memory, or anything that comes up in my mind but it won't work.

So hope that I can get some help here. Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

I figure out guys, my SVG file was rendered the wrong way (using a portable version of Photoshop so it may cause some issue), so chrome can't render it (But Firefox can)